# How To Find Out What Router/Switch ANOTHER Computer Is Connected To

Tags: python, networking, scapy, netsh, traceroute

This is somewhat of a repost from [Is there a way to find out the BSSID a computer is connected to in a local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877466/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-bssid-a-computer-is-connected-to-in-a-local-netwo) but there was no answer there so I will try to quantify more specifically what I am trying to do here.

I'm working on a project for my job where we have a very large network. The goal is to be able to guesstimate on a map where a given machine is on the campus by finding out what AP the device is connected to. I have worked in the past on something similar (much smaller scale) with Scapy and Python, so I know it's possible. Unfortunately, and fortunately, ICMP responses are disabled, rendering tracert's that point only to the building's main switch, followed by an immediate hop to the device (missing hops).

Doing testing with netsh, I can find the BSSID that any given computer on the domain is connected to when I am physically using the machine. In essence, the goal then here is to find a way to get the machine to report to me what the BSSID is of its own network connection, which would allow me to reference our network map and work on that.

I am using Python for the bulk of this program, as I've worked with Scapy before on similar tasks. I have code all prepared for resolving IP from hostname, mac from IP, etc etc. However, these functions are all working so until I resolve this there is no point in including that code in this post. I'm open to any alternative ideas, though I have tried scanning ports and running TCP traceroutes to no avail. Note: this is a Windows environment so Linux is out of the question, sadly. Show me what you've got!

Comment: You should look at the WLC. Bridges (switches and WAPs) are transparent devices that do not know about layer-3, so they do not respond to tracert or traceroute, which require a decrement to the layer-3 TTL. The WLC will know to which WAP the host is connected.